# why does it use A0 to define analog pin 0 in some case and why use 0 directly?

Tags: pins

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Knob

For first line of both examples(not in comments), it define the same pin, analog pin 0, but they use different values. why and can use A1, A2, etc. to define other analog pins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the source code. Keep in mind that for this answer, I'm assuming you have a standard Arduino Uno. For other Arduino platforms the values are different but the situation is the same.

If you look at the analog pin definitions in `hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h`, you'll find these lines:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
static const uint8_t A1 = 15;
static const uint8_t A2 = 16;
...
```

Which tells you that if you call `analogRead(A0)`, it is equivalent to calling `analogRead(14)`. So, really, the question is "How can calling `analogRead(0)` work?"

The answer to that is in `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c`. If you wade through the defines, you'll see that at the top of `analogRead`, there is the following code:

```
if (pin >= 14) pin -= 14; // allow for channel or pin numbers
```

The result is that passing either `0` or `A0` results in `0` being used in the `analogRead` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 0 to 5 for `analogRead` of pins A0 to A5. However if you want to do `digitalRead` or `digitalWrite` on those pins then you have to use `A0` through to `A5` in order to avoid confusing them with the digital pins 0 to 5 (on the other side of the board).

> can use A1, A2, etc. to define other analog pins?

Yes.